# two spaces in a NSAttributedString, my program crashed

Tags: ios, swift, crash, nsattributedstring

i have a string "tags: #新垣結衣# #aragaki  yui#",please note that there are two spaces between "aragaki" and "yui".
the i use a common method(string may contains link sometime) to change this string to a NSMutableAttributedString

[IMG for Code:convert string to NSMutableAttributedString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiajX.jpg)

then i use this attributedString to add some attribute ,it crashed in line of 85

[IMG for Code:add attribute to the attributedString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5yr.jpg)

just because there are two space characters, i delete one to make string from "#aragaki  yui#" to #aragaki yui#,it goes well,

crash info:

NSMutableAttributedStrings - objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds

somebody tell me why! thanks very much

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code directly in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the range based on your original text. You should calculate the range based on the NSAttributedString. BTW. post what your debugger says when it crashes.

Comment: thanks, i use the attributedString.length instead, and it worked. when i post the question here , the input sentence displayed here were just one space character. i knew the point. and i used the wrong length, make the wrong range